# Python Youtube video upload file

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

**couldn't find out how the video was defined in the way**

> video = "/Users/mac/Desktop/Sam/video.avi"

**I want to run and install this code**

```
import os
import google_auth_oauthlib
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().list(

    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)
```

Comment: how to add video file path here .?

Comment: probably using MediaFileUpload https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video